# Set center of rotation [Titanium]

Tags: image, rotation, titanium, center

I have got some code for rotation of an image. But however, the center of rotation is not equal to the center of the image which is to be rotated.

I have set the center of an image but I don't know how to set the center of the rotation.

Following is the code :

```
 // image code
var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    backgroundImage:'test.png',
    width: 650,
    height: 650,
    center:{x:CenterX, y:CenterY},
    align:'center'
});
//rotation code
image.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    var conv = e.source.convertPointToView({x: e.x, y:e.y}, win);

    var newAngle = Math.atan2(conv.y - 500, 380 - conv.x)* -(180 / Math.PI);  
    diff = (newAngle - old);

});

image.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){

      var conv = e.source.convertPointToView({x: e.x, y:e.y}, win);

      var newAngle = Math.atan2(conv.y - 500, 380 - conv.x)* -(180 / Math.PI);
      current = (newAngle-diff); 
      var t = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().rotate(current);
      wheel.transform = t;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the animation / view anchorPoint, on iOS you have to set the [Ti.UI.View's anchorPoint](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-anchorPoint), on Android you have to set the [Ti.UI.Animation's anchorPoint](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Animation-property-anchorPoint) or in your case, since your using a Matrix, just set the [anchorPoint of the Matrix](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/MatrixCreationDict-property-anchorPoint) on creation (for Android).

Here is what you do for **iOS**:

```
/* iOS */
var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    backgroundImage:'test.png',
    width: 650,
    height: 650,
    anchorPoint: {0.5, 0.5}, // ANchor point is at the center
});
```

Or alternatively, on **Android**:

```
/* Android */
// Matrix, inside your event listener
image.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){

    var conv = e.source.convertPointToView({x: e.x, y:e.y}, win);

    var newAngle = Math.atan2(conv.y - 500, 380 - conv.x)* -(180 / Math.PI);
    current = (newAngle-diff); 

    // Note that I set the anchor point here.
    var t = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix({anchorPoint: {0.5, 0.5}}).rotate(current);
    wheel.transform = t;
});
```

Comment: That sets the center for the image, right ? I want the center of rotation and image both of them to be the same ?

Comment: No, anchorPoint sets the rotation point of the image. Setting it to {0.5, 0.5} means the image will be rotated around its center.